# I want to understand the syntax of '__attribute__((space(dma)));'

Tags: c, xcode, microchip

I have to write a Stub for:

```
extern ECAN1MSGBUF  ecan1msgBuf __attribute__((space(dma)));
```

Can someone explain to me what makes this call, how it works and how I can write / use a stub for a test program? I have the hardware not at home and must write a test, but the XCode announces as a warning: unknown attributes space ignored. Otherwise I work on the MPLabX compiler / debugger with access to the hardware. There is not the problem, of course.

Comment: It declares `ecan1msgBuf` to be a variable of type `ECAN1MSGBUF`, that resides in a DMA space.

Answer (score 1):

DMA space on dspics is dual ported RAM that can be accessed without competing for memory bandwidth with the ALU (the actual CPU).

However, in some dspicE's (*) , DMA space is beyond the 32kb mark which needs *EDS* addressing. If so, you might want to view the sample code I posted about dspice CAN at http://www.microchip.com/forums/m790729.aspx#792226

Note that you can also use non dma space memory, the dma space memory is just more optimal.

(*) the ones with 56k memory, which are generally the 512KB flash parts for the GP and MU series.